# Как сформировать массив правильно?

Tags: javascript

ребята, подскажите как правильно добавить данные в json?
Нужно вот так:

```
"data": [
      {
        "23223cxv2": {
          "login": "23223cxv2",
          "password": "sada",

        },
        "dsffds": {
          "login": "23223cxv2",
          "password": "sada",
        }
      }
    ]
```

а получается вот так:

```
"data": [
  {
    "23223cxv2": {
      "login": "23223cxv2",
      "password": "sada",

    }
  },
  {
    "dsffds": {
      "login": "23223cxv2",
      "password": "sada",

    }
  }
]
```

т.е чтоб был только 0 индекс после data и обращаться напрямую к логину без цикла

вот код:

```
allAccounts.accounts[data] = []
let test = {}
test[req.body.data.login] = {
    login: req.body.data.login,
    password: req.body.data.password,
}

allAccounts.accounts[data].push(test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.assign(allAccounts.accounts[data][0], test);